# Why HMS Analytics kit in react native can not migrate to androidx?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

While implementing HMS Analytics kit in react native, can not migrate to androidx because it breaks the build with below error
**node_modules\react-native-ha-interface\android\src\main\java\com\huawei\hianalytics\HaInterfaceModule.java:37: error:
cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it on Native java project without androidx support by adding below in the gradle.build.
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:4.0.3.300'